# ASP.NET with EF 4 getting incorrect data from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I updated my ASP.NET site from Linq-to-SQL to EF 4. I've had a bunch of hiccups along the way but have ironed most out.

Not sure if it has anything to do with EF but recently my application has started going nuts at random times. I'll delete one or multiple records from my SQL Server database, but when I re-display the page that was listing those records they're still there. I check my database and the records are gone yet when my code queries for this data after it's deleted my data model is still getting that deleted data and displaying it on my site. The only way I've found to get around the issue is closing the web browser or stopping my local host when debugging. Obviously not the fix I want. It happens on server code and local host.

This problem is very rare and difficult to reproduce and it only happens some days but not most days. I'd like to say it's completely random but I know there has to be some variable and I can't figure it out. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked the cache?  Sounds like the results are being held in memory.

Comment: Are you caching data in your application?

Comment: There is a conflict in your dbcontext somewhere. Totally remove your database and DbContext from your project. Delete the connection strings from your Web Config. Create a new project in your solution... called DataModel (or something like that). Add your database to that solution. Add dependency references to the new project from the original project.

Comment: What's the lifespan of the context(s)?